# enlive remove html tag

Tags: clojure, enlive

I have this html snippet. I want parse that snippet and emit html without javascript tags

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="content">lorem ipsum</div>
        <script  src="/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

become this

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="content">lorem ipsum</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I couldn't found enlive helper function to remove tags.

I have found the solution thanks for the example. So I write this code and the js disappeared

```
(html/deftemplate template-about "../resources/public/build/about/index.html"
    []
    [:script] (fn js-clear [& args] nil)
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My usual approach when I need to conditionally remove some tags of the rendered page is to use a `nil returning` function.

For instance

```
(html/defsnippet upgrade-plan "page_templates/upgrade-plan.html" [:#upgradePlanSection]
  [pending-invoice ... ]
  ...
  [:#delayedPlanWarning] #(when pending-invoice
                            (html/at %
                                     [:#delayedPlanWarning] (html/remove-attr :style)
                                     [:.messagesText] (html/html-content (tower/t :plans/pending-invoice 
                                                                                (:id pending-invoice)))))
  ...
```

In that particular case if `pending-invoice` is `nil` the `delayedPlanWarning` element is removed from the rendered html since the function returns `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the extra parsing and emitting, the following would do nicely:

```
(def orig (html-resource (java.io.StringReader. "<html>
<body>
    <div class=\"content\">lorem ipsum</div>
    <script  src=\"/js/jquery.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>
    <script src=\"/js/bootstrap.min.js\" type=\"text/javascript\"></script>
</body>
</html>")))
(def stripped (transform orig [(keyword "script")] (substitute "")))
(apply str (emit* stripped))
```

Answer (score 0):

When removing whole tags, you only need to use `nil` as your transformation.

```
(deftemplate tester1
             (java.io.StringReader. "<html><body><div class=\"content\">...")
             []
             [:script] nil)

(template1)
```

In your case, you would replace the `StringReader` with the resource you are using.